# AWS Athena & AWS Glue column issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am having an issue with Athena having used AWS Glue to crawl an S3 bucket and create a table. The table created had a column type which was defined as a struct. I manually changed the type to String in the definition as I wish to use the contents by casting it to JSON.

However when I attempt to quert the data in Athena I receive

**HIVE_PARTITION_SCHEMA_MISMATCH: There is a mismatch between the table and partition schemas. The types are incompatible and cannot be coerced.**

This is because the partitions created automatically from the crawler refer to the changed column type as its old type (not the updated string type). I can't see how I can edit the partitions but also there are thousands of them as one is generated per folder so doing so manually could be difficult.

Does anyone have a way of editing a table scheme that also updates the partitions generated for it?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try running the crawler again on the data set.?

Comment: Hey @srini yes I tried rerunning with the appropriate update setting but it seemed to do nothing.

Comment: What is the file format of the objects stored in bucket?